# Pycharm doesn't recognize Anaconda's virtual environment

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I am learning how to use TensorFlow, so I installed Anaconda and then, as instructed, created a virtual environment, via

```
conda create -n tensorflow
source activate tensorflow
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

And proceeded to validate that everything was installed successfully. Now I want to use this virtual env in Pycharm, so I go to preferences -> Interpreter -> Add local, and go to what I assume is the correct file to point to, `/Users/myusername/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/bin/conda`, but I get an error message,
`The selected file is not a valid home for Python SDK`.
What am I doing wrong? Is it another file I should be pointing to? how do I use the virtual env

Comment: Have you tried using a shebang instead of manually adding an environment? Try adding this directory where your python executable exists in your environment to the very top of the script `#!/Users/myusername/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/python`.

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter should be pointing to python instead of conda. For example, the interpreter should be

```
/Users/myusername/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/bin/python
```